# How can I completely replace the react-navigation header?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm not simply trying to replace the left middle or right components, I want to replace the whole header so that I can use the Toolbar from react-native-material-ui.

Answer (score 3):

You can override a `header` property in your `navigationOptions`:

```
import { HeaderBackButton } from 'react-navigation'

class Foo extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = (navigationProps) => {
    return {
      header: (props) => (
        <MyCustomHeaderContainer>
          <HeaderBackButton
            onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack(null)}
            tintColor="#fff"
          />
          <ContentComponent />
        </MyCustomHeaderContainer>
      ),
    };
  }
}
```

This assumes that `Foo` component is routable, e.g.

```
StackNavigator({
  Foo: {
    screen: Foo,
  },
});
```

**UPD:** You can also specify `navigationOptions` at the moment you create a navigator. This may be handy in some cases, e.g. nested navigation:

```
const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({...});

export default StackNavigator({
  MainNavigator: {
    screen: MainNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: navigationProps => <YourHeaderComponent {...navigationProps} />
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, Foo is inside a TabNavigator that's inside a StackNavigator!

Comment: Hi @sorinLates! Sorry, it wasn't clear from your initial question. I've updated my answer in order to add some information to address your case.

Comment: Still no luck, my exact architecture is: `<StackNavigator><DrawerNavigator><TabNavigator/></DrawerNavigator></StackNavigator>`... I'll probably just not show any header and construct a custom toolbar...

Comment: This worked for me. However, the icons are not being displayed properly and the back arrow no longer works. How do you fix that? @AlexeyKureev